# dlsym() returns a undefined symbol

Tags: android, c++

The Code:

```
bool mlovinit(){
    handle = NULL;
    handle = dlopen("libGLESv2.so", RTLD_NOW);//libGLESv2.so
    if(!handle){
        LOGE("Cannot open library: %s", dlerror());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void LogShaders(){
    dlerror();
    auto p_glGetUniformLocation = (const void*(*)(...))dlsym(handle, "glGetUniformLocation");//glDrawElements
    const char *dlsym_error = dlerror();
    if(dlsym_error){
        LOGE("Cannot load symbol 'glGetUniformLocation': %s", dlsym_error);
       return;
    }else{
        TiahhHook(reinterpret_cast<void*>(p_glGetUniformLocation), reinterpret_cast<void*>(new_glGetUniformLocation), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&old_glGetUniformLocation));
    }
}

void Wallhack(){
    dlerror();
    auto p_glDrawElements = (const void*(*)(...))dlsym(handle, "glDrawElements");//glDrawElements
    const char *dlsym_error = dlerror();
    if(dlsym_error){
        LOGE("Cannot load symbol 'glDrawElements': %s", dlsym_error);
        return;
    }
    else{
        TiahhHook(reinterpret_cast<void*>(p_glDrawElements), reinterpret_cast<void*>(new_glDrawElements), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&old_glDrawElements));
    }
}
```

what i get is:

> "Cannot load symbol 'glDrawElements': undefined symbol:
> Java_com_roblox_engine_jni_NativeGLInterface_nativeReleaseAllRbxEventStreams__"

Any help?

Comment: The highly technical term for this situation is called "putting the cart before the horse". Some prior call to `dlsym` failed. Your call to `dlsym` succeeds and returns a perfectly cromulent pointer. But the shown code ignores it what `dlsym` returned, calls `dlerror`, sees the completely unrelated error that happened somewhere else, maybe even for a completely different shared library, and puts the cart before the horse?

Comment: Yes probably you are right but i have noted with logcat that it doesn't give me anything. I cannot hook the glDrawElements function... the hook works perfectly in other functions. The dlsym returns error but with a offset... so am I really looking for a dlsym error or a hook problem? I cannot understand what happens in-game... I am thinking that the dlsym is not finding the right offset of glDrawElements same with glGetUniformLocation